# Matrix/Array multiplication - What's Excel doing (=MMULT) and how to mimic it in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, matrix

I want to reproduce a dataset in Excel which I found online in Python with Pandas. The data is depicted in the image below and I also added links to a CSV and Markdown file. There's a vector in cells *B2:M2* and a matrix in cells *B4:M1*. In Excel, in *B17:M17* there's the formula `{=MMULT(B2:M2,B4:M15)}`.

Let's assume *B2:M2* is the dataframe **E** and *B4:M15* is the dataframe **L**. How can I reproduce the results (E*L) in line 17 with Pandas?

Data as CSV : https://pastebin.com/raw/Q00ZWLCC

[image]

Edit: A solution in numpy would also work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am following your link:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/Q00ZWLCC', delimiter='\t')
vector = df.iloc[0, 1:]
matrix = df.iloc[2:14, 1:]
result = matrix.dot(vector)
```

this code multiplies the matrix shape = (12, 12) for a column vector (12, 1), obtaining a column vector (12, 1).

If you want to obtain a row vector (1,12) from the multiplication (1,12) x (12, 12), you can use numpy. Add the following to the previous code:

```
import numpy as np
v = vector.to_numpy()
m = matrix.to_numpy()
result_as_a_row_1_by_12 = np.dot(v, m)
```

This will work for you.
You could also transpose the matrix and stay in pandas, but I think this is a clearer solution.
Regards.

Comment: Sorry. Contrary to my previous comment, this is not what I am looking for. The numbers in your `result` dataframe are not the same as in line 17 of the image/code which I've provided.

Comment: Ok: so, you want to multiply a row vector (1,12) for a matrix (12, 12) and obtain a row vector (1, 12). That's why I asked you before. I'm amending my answer now. Take a look.